# Регулярное выражение (удаление подстрок)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

К примеру есть код:

```
$x = rand(1, 5);
$str = 'a1 a2 '.$x.' a4 a5';
```

Нужна регуляка которая буде удалять в `$str` начиная с a2 до a4, т.е. результат должен быть:

```
$str = 'a1  a5';
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем парится, регулярка проста как... что-то простое!

```
$str = preg_replace('!a2 \d a4!', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/a1.*?a5/', '', $str);
```

Comment: тогда `$str = '';`, чего уж там.

Answer (score 0):

Вы описали стандартную задачу для удаления подстрок, которые начинаются и заканчиваются с двойного сочетания символов. Например /* */. Если вы аналогию специально придумали, то получилось очень точно. Вот подходящая регулярка:

```
preg_replace('/a2(?:[^4]|[^a]4)*?a4/', '', $str);
```